# Issues while uploading big Database

Tags: mysql

I have a big database of about 700MBs. A single table is about 300MBs. I can change the php.ini to upload it but many times I got issues like time out or slow internet etc.

Is there a better and professional way to upload 700+ MBs database to phpmyadmin?

Comment: Could you buy a dedicated server?

Comment: no its a share hosting with cpanel

Comment: have you tried with mysql dump?

Comment: You can upload it via command prompt. Go to the appropriate folder where MySQL exists and run command to upload the database.
I am using Xampp, in my case...

C:\>cd xampp\mysql\bin\
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\> mysql -u root -p your_database_name < your_database_dump (which you want to upload)

Comment: Can you explain the relation between uploading that database and any setting in `php.ini`? Usually, there is no need to use PHP for this

Comment: How often do you do the load?

Comment: @NicoHaase the PHPMyAdmin usually didn't allow to upload more than 50MB. so i use php.ini to increase upload size

Comment: @AlokMali that is a great solution, thanks for that

Comment: You are most welcome @saleem

Answer (score 0):

Use [heidisql](https://www.heidisql.com/) to migrate the databases. This tool can chunk the data and move across the databases.

Go through follow [tutorial](https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/use-heidisql/) to migrate. And instead of file use database option, select the database option, then select the destination database.